# Calculating MODE (most common number in a set) in Sql Server Analysis Services

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is there a way to calculate the MODE in SSAS?  I see there are Microsoft provided functions for Median, AVG, Max, and Min but nothing for Mode.  Would I need to code a user defined function in .net to make this happen or is there an easier alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible alternatives. Creating a .Net stored proc is one, but there is a bit of overhead in calling those, so you would not want to run a Mode function over too many cells.

The other option, if there is not too large a number of distinct value that you need to operate across, is to create a dimension with an attribute based off the number. Then you could create a row count measure and get the mode by doing TOPCOUNT(... ,1) over the dimension with the numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a fact dimension (Degenerate dimension) of the numbers you are interested in the mode of, then using that against a count of rows, take the Top Count of 1?

Or are you after a more general MDX calculation that you could use for may scenarios?

Comment: I was after a more general calculation.  I came up with this but it is so slow that it is unusable.  It turned out that in my specific scenario the MODE was more than 50% of the values making it the same as the MEDIAN so I went ahead and used MEDIAN since it was built in.  

MEDIAN( [Billable Item].[Billable Item].[All].Children,
[Measures].[Contractual Adjustment - Billable Item] )

So far I have been unable to make it fast enough for production use though, it takes minutes on very small datasets.  I think I need to use EXISTS or some other sort of filter to speed it up.

Comment: @Shane - If this is a calculated member, setting the non empty behaviour is worth a go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166568.aspx It should make it faster if it's not set, but be careful as setting it wrong can produce wrong results.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
create table #temp (value int)
insert into #temp (value) values (1)
insert into #temp (value) values (1)
insert into #temp (value) values (1)
insert into #temp (value) values (2)
insert into #temp (value) values (2)
insert into #temp (value) values (3)
insert into #temp (value) values (3)
insert into #temp (value) values (3)
insert into #temp (value) values (3)
insert into #temp (value) values (3)
insert into #temp (value) values (3)
insert into #temp (value) values (4)


select value from (select top 1 count(*) as counts, value from #temp group by value order by count(*) desc) as myTemp
```

Comment: This was tagged as an MDX question, not a SQL question.  TSQL is not used in Sql Server Analysis Services so this won't solve my question.  Mode is easy enough to calculate in Sql Server, or even SSIS, but I need it done in SSAS for my needs.